# SharePoint-Search 2013 FQL not working after FQL is enabled manually

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

We have an WPF/MVVM application that uses SharePoint 2010 Search QueryService.  We are in the process of upgrading SharePoint 2010 to 2013.  I enabled FQL in SharePoint 2013 server by adding a new default Search ResultSource with Query Transformation string setup as “{?andnot({searchTerms},filter(contentclass:"urn:content-class:SPSPeople*"))}”.  This one enables FQL for SharePoint 2013 by looking at article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163973.aspx.

But our FQL search still return 0 results without any exceptions from Client Object Model.  I checked that we didn't use any deprecated operators under FQL CAML queries.  This web site http://www.onlysharepoint2013.com/2013/01/fast-query-language-fql-features-that.html lists all the deprecated operators for SharePoint 2013 FQL.

I tested the same FQL CAML query using SPCAMLQueryHelper.exe and it does return correct rows.

What could cause FQL CAML queries still not working on SharePoint 2013?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Sharepoint 2013 use keyword query language.

Pls see below link it will helps you.

http://technologybooth.blogspot.in/2013/08/keyword-query-in-sharepoint-2013.html